# Cannot add a table row because of "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Users' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF" error

Tags: sql, sql-server, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I tried to **save a user to the database using Spring boot and JPA** but it does not work for me because of this error.

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Users'
when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

*Error* is clear so I've **tried changing Identity** insert in my database which was successful but the error still occurs. The second thing that is strange in that issue that I'm not trying to put a specific value as id to my database.
Here's the exact line that is responsible for saving data:

```java
userService.save(new User("wikimmax","test","testmail@op.pl","test", Arrays.asList(new Role("ROLE_USER"))));
```

And there is my User class

```java
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Users",uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email"))
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Collection<Role> roles;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password, Collection<Role> roles) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Collection<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Collection<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", password='" + "*********" + '\'' +
                ", roles=" + roles +
                '}';
    }
}
```

There Is my table properties :

[image: There Is My table]

Any ideas are highly appreciated

**UPDATE** I've manage to print SQL query that is generated by hibernate and it looks like this:

```
    insert 
    into
        Users
        (email, firstName, lastName, password, id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: Why don't you allow SQL Server to manage the identity column and tell JPA to use `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)` instead?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help do you need any additional pieces of information?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning this is a great question ! feel free to upvote it ! I just upvoted Resul's answer also ! amazing work guys !

Answer (score 4):

Add following codes :

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please edit question and add insert statement.

you can't insert any data in identity column, because this columns fill the automatic by SQL engine, in `Insert` Statement remove the id column and try it again.

**Or** set identity on, but its not good idea.
Allows explicit values to be inserted into the identity column of a table.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Users ON
```

For Example :

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
-- Create tool table.  
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tool(  
   ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,   
   Name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL  
);  
GO  
-- Inserting values into products table.  
INSERT INTO dbo.Tool(Name)   
VALUES ('Screwdriver')  
        , ('Hammer')  
        , ('Saw')  
        , ('Shovel');  
GO  

-- Create a gap in the identity values.  
DELETE dbo.Tool  
WHERE Name = 'Saw';  
GO  

SELECT *   
FROM dbo.Tool;  
GO  

-- Try to insert an explicit ID value of 3;  
-- should return an error:
-- An explicit value for the identity column in table 'AdventureWorks2012.dbo.Tool' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.
INSERT INTO dbo.Tool (ID, Name) VALUES (3, 'Garden shovel');  
GO  
-- SET IDENTITY_INSERT to ON.  
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Tool ON;  
GO  

-- Try to insert an explicit ID value of 3.  
INSERT INTO dbo.Tool (ID, Name) VALUES (3, 'Garden shovel');  
GO  

SELECT *   
FROM dbo.Tool;  
GO  
-- Drop products table.  
DROP TABLE dbo.Tool;  
GO
```

Comment: It would be great to do that but spring performs SQL queries at by itself at the background do you know how I can change that manually?

Comment: Alternatively you could run `SET IDENTITY_INSERT Users ON`. This would allow you to explicitly insert values in column Users.Id, which might be a very bad idea depending on the exact reason it was set as identity in the first place.
To restore current behaviour just run  `SET IDENTITY_INSERT Users OFF`